# "Sticking" occurs in collision constraint solution

Tags: physics, collision-resolution, physics-engine, rigid-body-dynamics, joints

[image]

Two rectangles collide, use the following formula to calculate:

$$
 J = \begin{vmatrix}
J_{1} \\
J_{2} \\
J_{3} \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$
$$
J_{n} = \begin{vmatrix}
\overrightarrow{n} & \overrightarrow{r_{a}}\times \overrightarrow{\omega_{a}}  & -\overrightarrow{n} & -\overrightarrow{r_{b}}\times \overrightarrow{\omega_{b}} \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$
$$
 \lambda = (JM^{-1}J^{T})(-JV-b)
$$
$$
\bigtriangleup V = M^{-1}J^{T}\lambda  
$$

\$J_1, J_2, J_3\$ represents 3 collision points.
The problem now is: the "sticking" effect is found after solving. I think it's the reason why the lambda (\$\lambda\$) value is negative.

I tried clamping lambda to a value greater than 0 and using "warm start", but "overshoot" occurred again.

Is there any good solution?